# Assist "Solve[]" by Providing Variable Ranges

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve a system of equations (5 unknown variables, 5 equations) but the `Solve[]` function just hangs and I have to abort the evaluation. I can understand as some of the equations are quite messy-- in my opinion at least (I'm not a mathematician).

I checked the equations used in `Solve[]` by substituting in "known/true" simulation values and they all work out.

So, my question is this: Is it possible to "help" `Solve[]` by saying, for example...

```
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5},{var1, var2, var3, var4, var5}, (*code here along the lines of { 0 < var1 < 10, var2 < 25, ...}*)]
```

I can provide more information if it would be of assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar problem [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10279/134).

Comment: Placing ranges on variables can help when the system is not comprised of polynomial equations. If it is polynomials this very likely will not help, but then you might get faster results using NSolve. Alternatively, try for just single solutions numerically using FindRoot. This applies if you only need, say, one solution in your specified range, even when others may exist.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Wow, that looks really interesting! I'll give it a shot and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

The program *Mathematica* provides actually very simple solution inside the function `Solve[]`.
You can add all kind of desired conditions as inequalities `ConditionOnVar1, ConditionOnVar1`:

```
Solve[{Eq1, Eq2, ConditionOnVar1, ConditionOnVar2},{Var1, Var2}]
```

### Trivial 1D Example

```
Solve[Cos[theta]==1 && theta >= 0 && theta < 2\[Pi], theta]
```